# Подключение к Outline или OpenVPN на IOS используя C#

Tags: c#, ios, swift, vpn, openvpn

Здравствуйте многоуважаемые, пишу vpn-app на с# используя xamarin.forms и бла-бла-бла, и столкнулся с трудностью не имения в интернете адекватных документаций или репозиториев которые адекватно могли бы объяснить мне каким образом я могу создать vpn соединение на ios используя C#. Единственное что нашел - OpenVPN на ios в Swift, но сроки сильно жмут да и с swift я не знаком, как и с построением бриджей между c# и swift, что может быть могло бы решить мою проблему, но слишком долго и вообще не понятно для меня. В общем я прошу помощи у наших гениальных соотечественников в моём непростом вопросе. Буду очень благодарен за адекватную информацию. Может если у вас есть опыт в том что-бы подружить C# и Swift, и вы сможете мне примерно описать как это устроить, то я смогу выдернуть основной функционал [отсюда](https://github.com/deneraraujo/openvpnclient-ios), правильно скомпилировать этот Swift и решить свою проблему. Если я не справлюсь с этим то мне определённо что-то сломают, так что очень надеюсь на вашу помощь в моём или нашем непростом деле!